# Serializers in Foreign Key Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i need to get information from Reservation, ReservationDetails and Product, but just get Reservation and ReservationDetails

i have 3 models

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    userReservation = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    dateStart = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, default=datetime.now)
    dateFinish = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, default=datetime.now)
    date_Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_Modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class DetailsReservation(models.Model):
    Reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='reservation_details')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='products_reservation')
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    userbyReserva = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_Description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    Quantity_Max_Reservation = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    product_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    product_Status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='products')
    date_Created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    date_Modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

And i tried to create serializers

```
class ReservationDetailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model= DetailsReservation
        fields =  ['Reservation', 'Quantity', 'userbyReserva', 'products']


class ReservationDetailsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reservation_details = ReservationDetailsSerializers(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ['id', 'userReservation', 'dateStart', 'dateFinish', 'reservation_details']
```

but the response does not show this field

```
[
    {
        "id": "6d87ba1c-61bc-41bd-80c8-31a51df8d32f",
        "userReservation": 1,
        "dateStart": "2018-09-16T17:19:34-05:00",
        "dateFinish": "2018-09-16T17:19:35-05:00",
        "reservation_details": [
            {
                "Reservation": "6d87ba1c-61bc-41bd-80c8-31a51df8d32f",
                "Quantity": 1,
                "userbyReserva": 1
                >>"here should show this information product"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0ed26395-2579-4c40-9a63-460f5095ac51",
        "userReservation": 2,
        "dateStart": "2018-09-16T19:21:24-05:00",
        "dateFinish": "2018-09-16T19:21:24-05:00",
        "reservation_details": [
            {
                "Reservation": "0ed26395-2579-4c40-9a63-460f5095ac51",
                "Quantity": 1,
                "userbyReserva": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and it is my views.py

```
class getAllReservationDetails(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Reservation.objects.prefetch_related('reservation_details')
    print(queryset.query)
    serializer_class = ReservationDetailsListSerializer
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.queryset()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        return obj
```

I review this [Link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/), but i don't know, why doesn't show the information product.

But, that is not working as I wanted.

What should I do?

Comment: `products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), required=False)`
Shouldn't this also have `many=True`?

Comment: when add many=True, postman show me this error  'DetailsReservation' object has no attribute 'products'

Comment: Try using `serializers.SeralizerMethodField` as described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: What is ***this field*** here?

Comment: I don't understand your question,  what field here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try creating a serializer for the Product model and use it on the ReservationDetailsSerializers?

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class ReservationDetailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(source='product', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model= DetailsReservation
        fields =  ['Reservation', 'Quantity', 'userbyReserva', 'products']
```

You can find more about this topic on [Specifying nested serialization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

The **`DetailsReservation`** model has not attribute **`products`**, but it has **`product`**.
 So remove the "**s**" from **`products`** or use **`source = 'product'`** in ***`ReservationDetailsSerializers`*** serializer

---

**Method - 1** : removal of "**s**"

```
class ReservationDetailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model= DetailsReservation
        fields =  ['Reservation', 'Quantity', 'userbyReserva', 'product']
```

**Method - 2** : speciying ***`source`*** argument

```
class ReservationDetailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all(),
                                                  required=False, source='product')

    class Meta:
        model = DetailsReservation
        fields = ['Reservation', 'Quantity', 'userbyReserva', 'products']
```

### UPDATE

I think you need ***nested serializer representation***. If so, you've to define a *seperate serializer* (say `ProductSerializer`) and add it to **`ReservationDetailsSerializers`** instead of **`serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`**

```
#new serializer class
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__' # you can specify the fields here
```

Hence **Method-1** become

```
class ReservationDetailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model= DetailsReservation
        fields =  ['Reservation', 'Quantity', 'userbyReserva', 'product']
```

and the **Method-2** become

```
class ReservationDetailsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(required=False, source='product')
```

class Meta:
        model = DetailsReservation
        fields = ['Reservation', 'Quantity', 'userbyReserva', 'products']

Comment: In both cases, it only shows the identification of the product   >> "products": 1